# create trainingset and testset in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm working on a project and I need to build a machine learning model. I need to create a trainingset and testset based on rownames. I have been searching for hours, but I couldn't find the right code. 
I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(docnr= c("doc1", "doc1", "doc2", "doc2", "doc3", "doc3"),x = c(1,4,2,3,6,5), y = c(5,6,3,9,5,2))

docnr x y
 doc1 1 5
 doc1 4 6
 doc2 2 3
 doc2 3 9
 doc3 6 5
 doc3 5 2
```

Now I want to create a trainingset and testset based on the column `docnr`. So doc1 and doc3 must be in the traininset and doc2 must be in the testset, for example.

```
train = 
 doc1 1 5
 doc1 4 6
 doc3 6 5
 doc3 5 2

test = 
doc2 2 3
doc2 3 9
```

With the following code, I manage to create a train and test set. But that is not what I want.

```
smp_size <- floor(0.67 * nrow(df))
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(df)), size = smp_size)
train <- df[train_ind, ]
test <- df[-train_ind, ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to randomly generate `train` and `test`, you could first split your `df` by `docnr`, then shuffle the resulting list of dataframes according to your desired ratio; and finally rbind the dataframes into `train` and `test`.

```
# Split df per docnr
d1 <- split(df,df$docnr)

# Define ratio and shuffle
smp_size <- floor(0.67 * length(d1))
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(length(d1)), size = smp_size)

# define train and test
train <- rbindlist(d1[train_ind])
test <- rbindlist(d1[-train_ind])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try e.g.

```
train <- subset(df, docnr %in% paste0("doc", c(1, 3)))
test <- subset(df, !docnr %in% paste0("doc", c(1, 3)))
```

or

```
test <- setdiff(df, train)
```